# Add command to jQuery typing effect function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've started using jQuery and am trying to implement some sound effects into the page, specifically, typing sounds to match the typing algorithm.

I want it automatically turning off the typing sound sound on and off when it's finished typing the text (using document.getElementById('Type').pause())

Where do I insert the code? Placing a line of code after the jQuery simply executes it as it starts typing, not what I need.

Here's what I've got:

```
<head>
<title> Test</title>

<body>
<span style="font-size: 3.5em" id="holder1"></span>
<div  overflow-y: hidden;"><audio id="Type" src="Type.mp3" autoplay >
</body>
<script type= "text/javascript" src = "javascripts\jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type= "text/javascript">
//Function for typing

(function($) {
    $.fn.writeText = function(content) {
        var contentArray = content.split(""),
            current = 0,
            elem = this;
        setInterval(function() {
            if(current < contentArray.length) {
                elem.text(elem.text() + contentArray[current++]);
            }
        }, 100);

    };

})(jQuery);
$("#holder1").writeText("This is the first paragraph");

</script>
```

Comment: FYI, your interval timer runs forever.  You should stop it with `clearTimeout()` when it hits the end of your string.

Comment: Still new at this, where do i put it and does a variable go in the function?